# how to read/save a json file in nodeJs from angularjs $http.post

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, node.js, express

SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH

I have a problem trying to catch a json sended using $http.post fron an angularjs to a nodejs with express (i have to send it because i can not save in client side a file on the server)

i have this code in angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);
app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array
    $http.get("data/people.json").success(function(response){ 
        $scope.users = response; //this works well
    });
    $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.users.push({'id':$scope.users.length,'name':$scope.name,'age': $scope.age}); //this works well
    $http.post("data",$scope.users).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ //this send to the nodeJs the object
            console.log("success");
        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("error");
        });
}
});
```

and this in server nodeJs

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/data', express.static(__dirname + '/data/')); //this is for routing
app.post("/data", function(req,res){
    console.log(req); //this return me something (that i do not understand)***********
    console.log(req.name); //this return me undefined
THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE JSON THAT I SEND FROM ANGULARJS TO SAVE INTO A EXISTENT JSON FILE IN THE SERVER (/data/people.json)
});
app.listen(5050);´
```

this is the json file

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "age": 24,
    "name": "Mathis Hurst"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 38,
    "name": "Gallegos Ryan"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "age": 27,
    "name": "Jodi Valencia"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "age": 28,
    "name": "Jenna Anderson"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "age": 28,
    "name": "Horne Clark"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "age": 21,
    "name": "Briggs Walters"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "age": 27,
    "name": "Rena Higgins"
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "age": 32,
    "name": "Adrian Marquez"
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "age": 25,
    "name": "Alberta Ellison"
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "age": 20,
    "name": "Mcleod Stark"
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "age": 22,
    "name": "Neal Patrick"
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "age": 36,
    "name": "Williamson Roman"
}
```

]

this is what console.log(req); returns:

```
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 0,
     _bytesDispatched: 970,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5050' },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5050' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 0,
        _bytesDispatched: 244,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 2771,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 3075,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: 'localhost:5050',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '544',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     origin: 'http://localhost:5050',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     dnt: '1',
     referer: 'http://localhost:5050/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'accept-language': 'es-419,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     cookie: '___r56138=0.9179862105555572' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Host',
     'localhost:5050',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'Content-Length',
     '544',
     'Accept',
     'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Origin',
     'http://localhost:5050',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     'DNT',
     '1',
     'Referer',
     'http://localhost:5050/',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate',
     'Accept-Language',
     'es-419,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     'Cookie',
     '___r56138=0.9179862105555572' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/data',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: 
   Socket {
     _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 15,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 0,
     _bytesDispatched: 970,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5050' },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5050' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 0,
        _bytesDispatched: 244,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 2771,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 3075,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/data',
  _parsedUrl: 
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/data',
     path: '/data',
     href: '/data',
     _raw: '/data' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: 
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 0,
        _bytesDispatched: 970,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 3075,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 0,
        _bytesDispatched: 970,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 3075,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _header: null,
     _headers: { 'x-powered-by': 'Express' },
     _headerNames: { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By' },
     _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {} },
  route: Route { path: '/data', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }
```

Comment: in code comments you say "//this return me something (that i dondt understand)".  What *exactly* is it returning?  It's not possible to help you understand it if we can't see what it is.

Comment: share the output from `console.log(req);` in your question

Comment: already update the output. can you see it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to generate a json file within Node, first include the `fs` module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Next, add this snippet where you need the json file generated:

```
fs.writeFile('/data/people.json'), JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error writing /data/people.json');
    } else {
        console.log('JSON file written to /data/people.json');
    }
});
```

Comment: req.body returns me undefined

Comment: Sounds like you're not posting the data properly then

Comment: If you want additional assistance from me, please respond to the comment I left on your question

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing variables wrong.

on POST data, try req.body.yourvariable
on GET data, try req.query.yourvariable

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/data', express.static(__dirname + '/data/')); //this is for routing
app.post("/data", function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.name); // this should work.
    // your saving routine here.
});
app.listen(5050);
```

Comment: it gives me undefined, 
this is how i pass the json
`$http.post("data",$scope.users).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ //this send to the nodeJs the object
            console.log("success");
        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("error");
        });`

Comment: also try do this: $http.post("/data",$scope.users) <-- notice slash.

Comment: this is the error that i get:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Check your network tabs logs. In that case POST should not be successful. POST data isn't even getting to handler.

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: from your browser :) For example, you can start developer tools on firefox/chrome by clicking F12.